# Шаблонизация верстки

Tags: javascript, php, вёрстка, vue.js, шаблоны

Нашел вакансию - [Требования](https://krasnodar.hh.ru/vacancy/39728285?utm_source=adzuna.ru&utm_medium=meta&utm_campaign=RU_paid_cpc_applicant_feed_magic-1). Что такое шаблонизация верстки на примере Vue.js? Искал [шаблонизация верстки](https://www.google.ru/search?newwindow=1&sxsrf=ALeKk01aBrlSEh9zTosXDlu-XmwaGq5h8Q%3A1603175158188&source=hp&ei=9oKOX_K2CI6HrwTzxLvQAg&q=%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F%20%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B8&oq=%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F%20%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B8&gs_lcp=CgZwc3ktYWIQAzIECCMQJzoFCC4QsQM6BQgAELEDOgIIADoECC4QQzoECAAQQzoHCAAQFBCHAjoFCAAQzQI6BwgjELACECc6BAgAEA06BggAEA0QHjoICAAQDRAKEB46BAgAEAo6BAgAEB46BggAEAoQHjoGCAAQFhAeULoJWLZsYJt1aAVwAHgAgAF_iAHcEJIBBDIwLjWYAQCgAQGqAQdnd3Mtd2l6&sclient=psy-ab&ved=0ahUKEwjyicHuxMLsAhWOw4sKHXPiDioQ4dUDCAc&uact=5), но объяснения оказались размытыми и частичными. Приведите пожалуйста полные и четкие объяснения (желательно по пунктам).

Comment: классический верстальщик берет картинку и делает из нее статический html макет. Поскольку в данном случае при верстке вы используете различные конструкции в виде циклов, подстановки значения и т.п., то это уже шаблон, а не статичный макет. Так что от вас требуют знания vue. для пхп разработчика это бы значило знакомство с какими нить twig, smarty и т..п шаблонизаторами.

Comment: Шаблонизация верстки... template ... Может быть имелось в виду просто синтаксис шаблонов? Вот раздел под это https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html. А вообще можно у самой фирмы спросить, так как они оперируют не устоявшимся термином, вкладывая в это значение все что угодно

Answer (score 0):

Ну я думаю, что в данном контексте имеется ввиду разделение верстки на Vue-компоненты для их дальнейшего переиспо́льзования.
Хотя согласен, что написано"так себе"

Comment: Типичные работодатели, которые хотят найти человека, работающего за 2 стакана зерна)))

Answer (score 0):

Вероятно, имеется ввиду [Single File Components](https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/single-file-components.html) (SFC).